# Mutual inductance

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I need to find the mutual indutance of the system consisting of a infinity straight line and a circular loop (I is the current in both).

The center of the loop is a distance D away from the line.

The radius of the loop is a

[image]

I just tought that the magnetic field is the same in the "rectangular" part of the loop, since it is equidistance to the straight line. I would calculate the flux and divide it by I to find the mutual indutance.

So the flux would be:

$$F = \int B da\\B = \mu I /(2 \pi x)\\da = 2a^2sin^2\phi d\phi\\F =  \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{2 \mu I a^2sin^2\phi d\phi}{2 \pi (D+acos\phi)} = Diverges. $$

Not sure what is wrong here. Of course i am considering that the loop closes, or in another words, ignoring that part at the right, since nothing was said about that.

Comment: Your derivation looks fine. I don't see why the integral should diverge. The free online *Wolfram* integrator times out, but that doesn't mean that there's anything wrong. It gave me an answer when I used D = 2a.

Comment: I solved for the integration part by hand and got $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {\sin ^2 x}{d + a \cos x} \mathrm {d}x = \frac {\pi d}{2a^2} \left ( \frac {\sqrt {d^2 - a^2}}{\sqrt {d^2 - 2a^2}} - 2 \right). $

Comment: Thus your mutual inductance is $\displaystyle M =  \frac {\mu_{0} d}{2} \left ( \frac {\sqrt {d^2 - a^2}}{\sqrt {d^2 - 2a^2}} - 2 \right). $